# How to create jumping animation

Tags: java

I want to create very simple jumping animation - after user HITS space, the character jumps (goes up the axis for 400px and down). The problem is setting the restriction of jumping (that 400px). Pressing space initiates animation, letting it go changes nothing, and the character goes up without stopping at 400px.

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
{
    int key = e.getKeyCode();

    if(key == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE) {
        if(y > 400) {
            dy = -1;
        } else {                
            dy = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

y is the coordinate of the character, dy changes y in `actionPerformed()` method.

So hitting space below 400px changes dy to -1 and never to 0 again. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I'm gonna assume it's because it's never hitting that method again. I think if you pressed space, waited 'til the character goes up that 400px and then pressed space again it would go back down. So...you need some way of saying "Hey, if this guy is jumping I need to run a check to see where his vertical position is. If it's 400px or more, I need to bring him back down." and then have another flag saying he's falling and check to make sure he makes it back to the ground safely.

Comment: Ya, but you can't do that because isn't that they key press event? So that method will only be triggered if a key is pressed. You need some other method in your game loop that's checking his height as he's rising/falling to check his y-position and then respond accordingly.

Comment: Have a boolean isJumping, and use that.

Comment: In order to have a "nice" jumping animation, you'll have to consider the jumping direction, velocity and gravity. Otherwise the character would, in the best case, just move up and down with constant speed. You might find some inspiration about such a movement in http://stackoverflow.com/a/21785654

Comment: You actually need to program in Active Rendering, that means you dirty check at quick intervals changes in your view and redraw as quick as possible. You seem to use Passive Rendering which is great for UI, but often bad for games.

Answer (score 0):

You could introduce gravity, gravity can be a constant force pushing your sprite downwards, where every update, the time elapsed times a specific amount of velocity is added to your Y velocity. Then when the user presses jump, you give your Y velocity some negative value. During every update, the sprite will slow the jumping down towards the peak of the jump, and then start to fall back down slowly while picking up speed. The trick here is to pick a large enough initial negative Y velocity to get to the desired height.

If your velocities are being specified by pixels per millisecond, adding an amount of gravity of around .01 to .04 to your Y velocity should be a good number to start testing with.