# Smoother 2D animation with projectile physics

Tags: java, physics, projectile

So a while ago I posted [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23859015/how-to-get-smoother-2d-projectile-physics) question. And I followed the answer that I was given because It made sense. So I built my main while loop like so:

```
while(running){
            endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            frametime = (endTime - startTime);
            test.update(frametime/1000);
            test.repaint();
            System.out.println(test.yvel + " " + startTime + " " + frametime);
            startTime = endTime;

            try{
                if(1000/30 > System.currentTimeMillis() - endTime)
                    Thread.sleep((long) (1000/30 - (System.currentTimeMillis() - endTime)));
            }
            catch(Exception e){}

        }
```

Which fixed the "smooth-ness" of the animation.... however the physics part was destroyed... i figured it out that it takes 33 milliseconds to go through the whole loop and so the frametime is always equal to 33, stopping the ball from properly updating. I have been working on this for the past hour and a half trying to think of new ways to fix it and I came up with a question... Is the way i'm trying to do this not working because there is no change in the amount of time it takes to process the while loop? say if I made a game which may be updating a player or something making the while loop longer at some points more than others, would that then cause the ball to update correctly?.... Im starting to think i just need some sort of timer in order to get this working properly XD

Comment: An actual [runnable example that demonstrates your problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would involve less guess work and better responses

Comment: Just a heads up: using `System.out.println` in your main loop is pretty bad idea. Console write is a blocking operation which might actually take a while.

Comment: Check again the other question, the answer has been updated. There was a very grave omission in the physics simulation code which was `v+=a*dt; x+=v;` and should be `v+=a*dt; x+=v*dt`.