# Java 2D Platformer Gravity Improvements

Tags: java, game-physics

I have started making a small game in Java, and have put in collisions, and a form of gravity, the speed of the player does not increase as it falls like in real life. I'd like to improve on this form of gravity to make it more realistic, also I have a collision block for the floor, and when the player walks off the floor, it stays at that height and does not fall.

Below is my Player class:

```
    import java.awt.Color;
    import java.awt.Graphics2D;
    import java.awt.Rectangle;

    public class Player {
        private int x, y, width, height, lx, ly, dx, dy;
        private final int FallSpeed = 2;
        private final long JumpingTime = 8;
        public boolean jumping = false, falling = true;

        public Player(int x, int y, int width, int height) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            this.width = width;
            this.height = height;
            lx = x;
            ly = y;
            dx = x;
            dy = y;
            new Thread(new gravityThread()).start(); // Make user fall in case they are in the air
        }

        public void setX(int x) {
            this.x = x;
            lx = x;
            dx = x;
        }

        public void setY(int y) {
            this.y = y;
            ly = y;
            dy = y;
        }

        public int getX() {
            return x;
        }

        public int getY() {
            return y;
        }

        public int getWidth() {
            return width;
        }

        public int getHeight() {
            return height;
        }

        public Rectangle getBounds() {
            return new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);
        }

        public void update() {

        }

        public void move(int ax, int ay) {
            dx += ax;
            dy += ay;
            checkCollisions();
        }

        public void checkCollisions() {
            if (collided()) {
                falling = false;
                dx = lx;
                dy = ly;
            }
            x = dx;
            y = dy;
            lx = x;
            ly = y;
        }

        public boolean collided() {
            Rectangle desired = new Rectangle(dx, dy, width, height);
            for (Rectangle r : CollisionManager.collisions) if (r.intersects(desired)) return true;
            return false;
        }

        public void jump() {
            falling = false;
            jumping = true;
            new Thread(new gravityThread()).start();
        }

        public void render(Graphics2D g2d) {
            g2d.setColor(Color.black);
            g2d.fill(getBounds());
        }

        private class gravityThread implements Runnable {

            int i = 0;

            @Override
            public void run() {
                while(jumping) {
                    try {
                        i++;
                        Thread.sleep(JumpingTime);
                        move(0, -FallSpeed);
                        if (i == 40) {
                            jumping = false;
                            falling = true;
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                }
                while(falling) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(JumpingTime);
                        move(0, FallSpeed);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

In another class which handles drawing everything to the window, I control player movement with this snippet:

```
    public void onUpdate() {
            if (this.screenFactory.getGame().getKeyboardListener().isKeyPressed(KeyEvent.VK_A))
                player.move(-WalkSpeed, 0);
            if (this.screenFactory.getGame().getKeyboardListener().isKeyPressed(KeyEvent.VK_D))
                player.move(WalkSpeed, 0);

            if (this.screenFactory.getGame().getKeyboardListener().isKeyPressed(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE)) {
                if (!player.jumping && !player.falling)
                    player.jump();
            }

            if (player.getY() >= screenHeight - player.getHeight()) {
                player.setY(screenHeight - player.getHeight());
                player.falling = false;
            }
            if (player.getY() <= 0)
                player.setY(0);
            if (player.getX() >= screenWidth - player.getWidth())
                player.setX(screenWidth - player.getWidth());
            if (player.getX() <= 0)
                player.setX(0);
    }
```

Comment: Why do you process gravity in a special thread? There is no reason, I think. You could compute gravity in `onUpdate` method.

Comment: I processed in it's own thread so that the user can move whilst in the air, will they still be able to move in the `onUpdate` method?

Comment: To add physics you need an understanding of physics. How do you expect to be able to apply realistic physics if you don't understand them? Learn about speed, acceleration etc. in physics and you'll be able to add realistic falling.

Comment: @Tobias I understand how it works in real life, that the player will fall faster depending on time spent failing, but it doesn't mean I know how to implement it well.

Comment: I'd vote to close this as a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35478428/how-should-i-implement-jumping-gravity-falling-in-this-2d-java-game , but am hesitant to use the dupehammer here.

Comment: @Marco13 I did not see that post when I was searching for an answer, thank you for showing it to me!

Answer (score 1):

- g-force is 9.81 m/s²
- get your "draw-update-speed", this is s (to be realistic, you should update at least 30 times per second. have this in mind when calculating)
- get your definition of lengths, this is m

Cuple objects position depending on current speed v and accelleration (g-force) a  with each frame.
The longer something falls, the faster it will fall...

Edit: to make sideward movement while falling/jumping more realistic, you need to work with sin(), cos().